# $var(y)=b^2var(x)+var(e)$

Tags: regression, probability, variance, econometrics, inequality

Suposse $y=xb+e$ where $y$ and $x$ are random variable. $e$ is the error of the regression.

Since x and e are independent then:

$var(y)=b^2var(x)+var(e)$

How can I proof the following double implication?

$var(y)<var(x)$ iff $b^2<1-var(e)/var(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by assuming $b^2 < 1- \dfrac{\operatorname{Var}(x)}{\operatorname{Var}(e)}$.

Then, since $\operatorname{Var}(x)>0$

$$ b^2 \operatorname{Var}(x) < \operatorname{Var}(x) - \operatorname{Var}(e)$$

Add $\operatorname{Var}(e)$ to both sides and yield

$$ b^2 \operatorname{Var}(x) + \operatorname{Var}(e) = \operatorname{Var}(y) < \operatorname{Var}(x)$$

You still need to begin by assuming $\operatorname{Var}(y)< \operatorname{Var}(x)$ and then demonstrate the other inequality is true.